# Sweet alert 2 modal with input type range issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert2

is there any way to customize the output next to the input (type range) showing the value of the input?
i want it to show the value + %.

What i tried so far is to give the input a customclass and then get its `<output>` tag and tried to manipulate its inner text like this :

```
$(document).on('input', 'input', function () {
$(".customSwal output").text( $(".customSwal").val() + " %" ) 
});
```

with no particular success

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

Swal.fire({
    
  icon: 'question',
  showCancelButton:'true',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  title: 'Test',
  text: 'Test',
  input: 'range',
  width: '25rem',
  inputAttributes: {
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    step: 1,
   
    
  },
inputValue: 0,
  customClass: {
  input: 'customSwal',

}


})



});

//$(document).on('input', 'input', function () {
//$(".customSwal output").text( $(".customSwal").val() +  " %" ) 
//});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `%` character to range's output by simply adding this CSS:

```js
Swal.fire({
  input: 'range',
  inputAttributes: {
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
  },
  inputValue: 25
})
```

```css
.swal2-range output::after {
  content: '%';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(".customSwal output").text($(this).val() + " %")` to change value of `output` element . Also , you need to to use `change` event as well inside your handler .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  Swal.fire({

    icon: 'question',
    showCancelButton: 'true',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    title: 'Test',
    text: 'Test',
    input: 'range',
    width: '25rem',
    inputAttributes: {
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      step: 1,


    },
    inputValue: 0,
    customClass: {
      input: 'customSwal',

    }


  })
  //on load
  $(".customSwal output").text("0 %")

});
///when change occur 
$(document).on('input change', 'input[type=range]', function() {
  //get input value
  $(".customSwal output").text($(this).val() + " %")
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```